# How to use pseudo-register (like $t1) as part of file name for .writemem windbg command

Tags: windows, windbg

In short I want to create a breakpoint that will save part of memory to file and continue, something like this:

```
bp mymodule!MyReader::issueRead+0x2e ".writemem C:\writemem\write_$t1 rdx L r8; g"
```

$t1 is a counter incremented in other breakpoint. Problem is that $t1 (or ${$t1} is not resolved in file name and I'm ending with file called "write_$t1"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinDbg's scripting is always a bit hacky. The following seems to work, although I didn't apply it to a breakpoint yet:

```
aS /c filename .printf "c:\\writemem\\write_%i", $t1; .block {.writemem ${filename} 00ba0000 L1}; ad filename
```

When you apply it to a breakpoint you probably have to escape the quotation marks again.

`aS` defines an alias, `/c` does that by using a command. In this case, I format a string using `.printf`. Then the variable `filename` is defined.

WinDbg expands aliases immediately, i.e. it does that at a time when `filename` is not defined yet. Therefore I use `.block` to create a new scope.

Finally, `ad` deletes the alias again.